# Import a python module from a subdirectory of a parent directory

Tags: python, python-import

I have a directory structure like this

```
dir1/subdir1/module1.py
dir1/subdir2/subdir22/module2.py
```

Assume that I am adding __init__.py to each of the directories & sub directories. I want to import module1 from module 2, after referencing related questions and trying different ways, I couldn't find the solution. For example

in module2 I tried to import module 1 like

```
from .... import subdir1.module1
from ....subdir1 import module1
```

Both the above imports throw syntax errors.

Comment: Well in the second you have `module 1` not `module1`... Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.dirname(path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__))) ) ) )

from dir1.subdir1 import module1
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$ mkdir -p dir1/subdir1
$ mkdir -p dir1/subdir2/subdir22
$ touch dir1/{,subdir1,subdir2,subdir2/subdir22}/__init__.py
$ echo 'x = 42' > dir1/subdir1/module1.py
$ echo 'from ...subdir1.module1 import x; print x' > dir1/subdir2/subdir22/module2.py
$ python -m dir1.subdir2.subdir22.module2
42
```

The magic incantation is

```
from ...subdir1.module1 import x
```

though

```
from ...subdir1 import module1
```

also works.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can load a module from a path even if not inside a package or not on default path (module here is `Contemplate` an engine of mine), you should have an dummy `__init__.py` file in that folder though:

```
import imp
ContemplateModulePath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../src/python/')
try:
    ContemplateFp, ContemplatePath, ContemplateDesc  = imp.find_module('Contemplate', [ContemplateModulePath])
    Contemplate = getattr( imp.load_module('Contemplate', ContemplateFp, ContemplatePath, ContemplateDesc), 'Contemplate' )
except ImportError as exc:
    Contemplate = None
    sys.stderr.write("Error: failed to import module ({})".format(exc))
finally:
    if ContemplateFp: ContemplateFp.close()

if not Contemplate:
    print ('Could not load the Contemplate Engine Module')
    sys.exit(1)
else:    
    print ('Contemplate Engine Module loaded succesfully')
```